# Ununtu 16.04 "This site cannot be reached" Because of nameserver 127.0.1.1

Tags: 16.04

"This site cannot be reached". This started happening several updates ago, before that, never a problem. Now I have to edit the resolv.conf file to change the server from 127.0.1.1 to 8.8.8.8. I have another computer running Ubuntu 16 that I have not updated and it works fine. What changed? Why isn't this fixed?

Comment: and what resolv.conf file have you editted? if `/etc/resolv.cconf` do take note of the " do not edit" at the top and the mentioning of the manual page on how to add a DNS when using systemd (also probaly the answer to your question probably: 18.04 uses systemd`. Your 16.04 might  not).

Comment: Is there any improvement if you do: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I edit the resolv.conf file. I note the do not edit but I have to edit the server name to 8.8.8.8 to be able to get to web sites. The file is reset back to 127.0.1.1 when Ubuntu is rebooted.  I will try the above suggestion.